# Docusign SFDC Custom Button - Error

Tags: docusignapi

We're looking to create a custom button, however after following the sample documentation we're still seeing when clicking the button.  The error message being displayed: "Unexpected identifier"

This was the article used for reference.
https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/dfs-admin-guide-sample-js-code-custom-buttons

I will attach our custom code for your review.  Can you please help identify the issue?  Thanks!

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")} 

//********* Option Declarations (Do not modify )*********// 
var RC = '';var RSL='';var RSRO='';var RROS='';var CCRM='';var CCTM='';var CCNM='';var CRCL=''; var CRL='';var OCO='';var DST='';var LA='';var CEM='';var CES='';var STB='';var SSB='';var SES='';var SEM='';var SRS='';var SCS ='';var RES=''; 
//*************************************************// 


var CRL="Email~{!Opportunity.Primary_Contact_Email__c};FirstName~{!Opportunity.Primary_Contact_First_Name__c};LastName~{!Opportunity.Primary_Contact_Last_Name__c};Title~{!Opportunity.Primary_Contact_Title__c};Role~Signer1;RoutingOrder~1;Email~jonathan@epigrowth.com;FirstName~Jonathan;LastName~Gav;Title~Consultant;Role~Signer2;RoutingOrder~2"; 


//var CCTM = 'Signer1~Signer;Signer2~Signer';// 

//var CCRM = 'Signer1~Signer1;Signer2~Signer2';// 

var LA = '0'; 

var CES='Sales documents from {!Opportunity.OwnerFullName} are ready to be signed.'; 

var CEM = "Here is the document that requires your signature. Signing electronically is our preferred option. Please click on the View Documents button below and you will be taken to the document, where you will see an option to sign.\\n\\nYou can also sign and fax back by pressing View Documents and select Sign On Paper. Please note that if you choose to fax, please only use the DocuSign provided cover sheet. \\n\\nPlease contact me with any questions.\\n\\nThank You\\n\\n{!Opportunity.OwnerFullName} \\n{!Opportunity.OwnerEmail} \\n{!Opportunity.OwnerPhone}"; 

//********* Page Callout (Do not modify) *********// 
window.location.href ="/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Opportunity.Id}&RC="+RC+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES; 
//*******************************************//
```

Answer (score 1):

you have an extra `,` at the end of your CRL

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I made the appropiate updates and found a couple other typos.  Now getting this error "missing ; before statement"

Comment: CES is missing ```;``` at the end of the string

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  I updated that, and now I'm getting "unexpected identifier".  Thoughts?

Comment: Hi @Andrew - the code has been updated.  Thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: Also, as I'm continuing to test, I'm getting this error "Error: Configuration Error. Please contact your system administrator for assistance."   I set-up a new demo Docusign account to sync to our SFDC sandbox and still get the same error.  This is new (as I didn't get it last week).

Comment: @Jonathan the only thing I notice is that the CES value should be wrapped in double quotes for the {} replacement to work. The error that you're seeing now sounds like a setup issue. I would contact DocuSign Customer Support for that issue.